# How do I recurse into list returned by PySVN.Client.list()?

Tags: python, pysvn

I am using PySVN to get some repository info.

I used [Client.list](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_list) `entries_list = client.list("https://myrepourl.com/myproject", ...)` which "returns a list with a tuple of information for each file in the given path."

I would like to get only single information from the list/tuple, and that's whether the URL has some properties set (`has_props` - `bool` - True if the node has properties).

How do I recurse into `entries_list` and return a list of remote http paths, but only those paths with `has_props` set to `True`?

Edit:

```
entries_list {list}
  000 {tuple}
    0 {instance}
      data {dict}
        'path' = https://myrepourl.com/myproject/somedirorfile1
        'has_props' = 1
        'kind' = dir
  001 {tuple}
    0 {instance}
      data {dict}
        'path' = https://myrepourl.com/myproject/somedirorfile2
        'has_props' = 1
        'kind' = file
  002 {tuple}
    0 {instance}
      data {dict}
        'path' = https://myrepourl.com/myproject/somedirorfile3
        'has_props' = 0
        'kind' = dir
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data of entries_list?

Comment: It's so complicated, I can't copy it!

Comment: just post the first value in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `has_props` element could be accessed:

```
has_props = entries_list[0][0][‘has_props’]
```

And this is how to loop and search through the whole list:

```
entries_list = client.list("https://example.com/svnrepository/product",...)

for entry in entries_list:
    data_dict = entry[0]
    has_props = data_dict['has_props']

    if has_props == 1:
        print "Found props."
```